# two level menu - second level doesn't appear

Tags: html, css, navigation

I have created two level vertical menu. On mouse over, second level should appear, but it doesn't.

The first level menu is ul.side_nav, the second level menu is ul.side_sub_nav. I thought that the following should show second menu on mouse over:

```
.side_nav li:hover>ul.side_sub_nav>li {
    color: red;
    display:block; //it was display:none; before
}
```

Here is my full code:

```
<ul class="side_nav">
    <li class="li_sb "> <a href="index.php?p=subcategories_list&amp;cat=1">Vie professionnelle</a>

    </li>
    <ul class="side_sub_nav">
        <li>Vie professionnelle - subc2</li>
        <li>Vie professionnelle - subc1</li>
    </ul>
    <li class="li_sm "> <a href="index.php?p=subcategories_list&amp;cat=4">Administration et droit</a>

    </li>
    <ul class="side_sub_nav">
        <li>Administration et droit - subc1</li>
        <li>Administration et droit - subc2</li>
    </ul>
    <li class="li_sp "> <a href="index.php?p=subcategories_list&amp;cat=5">Vie pratique</a>

    </li>
    <ul class="side_sub_nav">
        <li>Vie pratique - subc1</li>
        <li>Vie pratique - subc2</li>
    </ul>
    <li class="li_sh "> <a href="index.php?p=subcategories_list&amp;cat=6">Immobilier et logement</a>

    </li>
    <ul class="side_sub_nav">
        <li>Immobilier et logement - subc1</li>
        <li>Immobilier et logement - subc2</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

css:

```
.side_nav {
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-image: none;
    width: 250px;
    margin-bottom: 37px;
}
.side_sub_nav {
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-image: none;
    width: 250px;
    display: none;
}
.side_nav li {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 8px center, 232px center;
    height: 42px;
    line-height: 42px;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-left: 45px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.side_sub_nav li {
    background-color: #008ec9;
    height: 42px;
    line-height: 42px;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-left: 22px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
}
.side_nav li a, .side_sub_nav li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #3f3f3f;
}
.side_nav li:hover, .side_nav li.active {
    background-color: #008ec9;
}
.side_nav li:hover a, .side_nav li.active a {
    color: white;
}
.side_nav li:hover>ul.side_sub_nav>li {
    color: red;
    display:block;
}
```

jsfiddlE: http://jsfiddle.net/Sggsz/

**EDIT:**
I need that first and second level menu are displayed one after another. So when second level appears, it should push first level items down.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED ANSWER 2**

We still have nested `<ul class="side_sub_nav">` inside the list item `<li>`.  But this time around we are targeting the anchor tags `<a>` in the list items `<li>`.  So all the styling that was being applied to the list items are now being applied to the anchor tags. I also added anchor tags to the second level list items which you did not have before.

I think the main issue you were having is that your second level menus were siblings (adjacent) to the elements you were hovering at the top level.  This made it hard to target.

Here is an updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sggsz/6/, along with the HTML and CSS below.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="side_nav">
     <li class="li_sb ">
          <a href="index.php?p=subcategories_list&amp;cat=1">Vie professionnelle</a>
          <ul class="side_sub_nav">
               <li><a href="#">Vie professionnelle - subc2</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Vie professionnelle - subc1</a></li>
          </ul>
     </li>
     <li class="li_sm ">
          <a href="index.php?p=subcategories_list&amp;cat=4">Administration et droit</a>
          <ul class="side_sub_nav">
               <li><a href="#">Administration et droit - subc1</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Administration et droit - subc2</a></li>
          </ul>
     </li>
     <li class="li_sp ">
          <a href="index.php?p=subcategories_list&amp;cat=5">Vie pratique</a>
          <ul class="side_sub_nav">
               <li><a href="#">Vie pratique - subc1</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Vie pratique - subc2</a></li>
          </ul>
     </li>
     <li class="li_sh ">
          <a href="index.php?p=subcategories_list&amp;cat=6">Immobilier et logement</a>
          <ul class="side_sub_nav">
               <li><a href="#">Immobilier et logement - subc1</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Immobilier et logement - subc2</a></li>
          </ul>
     </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.side_nav, .side_sub_nav {
    list-style: none;
    width: 250px;
}
.side_nav {
    margin-bottom: 37px;
}
.side_sub_nav {
    display: none;
}
.side_nav li:hover .side_sub_nav {
    display:block;
}
.side_nav a,
.side_sub_nav a {
    height: 42px;
    line-height: 42px;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.side_nav a {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 8px center, 232px center;
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 205px;
    padding-left: 45px;
    display: block;
    color: #3f3f3f;
}
.side_sub_nav a {     
    background-color: #008ec9;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-left: 22px;
    color: white;
}
.side_sub_nav a:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

**ANSWER 1**

You should be nesting your sub menu in your list elements like so:

**HTML**

```
<ul class="side_nav">
     <li class="li_sb ">
          <a href="index.php?p=subcategories_list&amp;cat=1">Vie professionnelle</a>
          <ul class="side_sub_nav">
               <li>Vie professionnelle - subc2</li>
               <li>Vie professionnelle - subc1</li>
          </ul>
     </li>
     <li class="li_sm ">
          <a href="index.php?p=subcategories_list&amp;cat=4">Administration et droit</a>
          <ul class="side_sub_nav">
               <li>Administration et droit - subc1</li>
               <li>Administration et droit - subc2</li>
          </ul>
     </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.side_sub_nav {
     display: none;
}
.side_nav li:hover .side_sub_nav {
     display: block;
}
```

Comment: Probably, this could be the right sollution, but in this case I have some problems with element position. Second level should appear just under the first level, if I change layout as you suggest, then there are problems...

Comment: And is it possible to have second level under the first level. Now there is some padding on the left when second level apperas. This probably is because padding-left for ul, but I need this padding for ul.li, but not for ul.li.ul...

Comment: Not sure I follow?  Just change the padding for the second level menu's `ul`.  It's the browser's default padding doing this.

Answer (score 0):

The selector you are using is looking for `ul.side_sub_nav` as a direct sibling to `.side_nav li:hover`. However, your markup has your `.side_sub_nav` as a sibling, so the styling you specified will not be applied.

What I believe you're looking for is the direct sibling selector. Instead of using `>`, use `+` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
I changed a little bit your code: 
http://jsfiddle.net/Sggsz/4/
```

Comment: I need that first and second level menu to be displayed one after another. When second level appears, it should push first level items down.

Comment: Check my updated answer.  It is similar to @Vismari second fiddle but mine retains the gray block around each element at the top level instead of expanding.  Not sure if this is the desired result.